# AsyncTaskLoader: onLoadFinished not called after orientation change

Tags: android

I have a `AsyncTaskLoader` with a long running task, when, while the loader is running, my activity is being destroyed due to an orientation change, the `onLoadFinished` callback isn't called.

Can I somehow 'reattach' the loader to my new Activity / it's callback?

Here's my (simplified) **Activity**:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends BaseActivity {

StartupCallback startupCallback;
    boolean loading = false; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.empty_viewpager);
    startupCallback = new StartupCallback();

    if (!loading){
         getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(GlobalApp.giveId(), null,
                startupCallback);
                 loading = true; 
    }
}


private class StartupCallback implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Boolean> loader, Boolean succ) {

        Log.d("LOG", "onLoadFinished"); 
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Boolean> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        return new StartupLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Boolean> loader) {

    }
}

}
```

I can not just start another loader with a new callback because the loader does database stuff and two loader working on the same database will crash the app.

Comment: I think your problem is restarting activity. By default android recreate activity when you change orientation. To prevent this add read about android:configChanges here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: Thanks, but as you said that's the default behaviour and I don't want to change it; stopping the Activity from restarting on orientation change might work here but bring me in trouble elsewhere  where I might encounter the same problem.

Comment: how looks your new StartupLoader? code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

During orientation change your Activity is destroyed and recreated, but the loaders are not.

It is worth noting, that a call to initLoader() does not necessarily *starts another* loader.
If the loader adressed by the specific ID exists, it is *reused* by LoaderManager and your callbacks are reattached to it. So you can remove  your (!loading) condition, and call initLoader in *every* onCreate() callback. Just make sure the loader's ID is the same.

See also [Loader guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, as long as the id is the same as the one you first passed it, it should return the current loader rather than a new one: [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29)

Answer (score -8):

Adding `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` to my activity did the trick for me.